# closest nonzero element in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

A matrix of dimensions n*n contains only zeros and ones as elements. Write psuedo code to find the closest non zero element for every element with least complexity.

•   Distance is Euclidean

Input Matrix

0 0 0

0 0 0

0 0 1

Output

Sqrt(8)   sqrt(5)   2

Sqrt(5)    sqrt(2)   1

2            1       0

I know the brute force method But I was trying to apply a faster solution and thought of matrix as graph and then applying the shortest path algo.Am I going in the right direction? I need little help on thinking

EDIT: There was hint given with the question also it is

Hint

•   First solve for one dimentsion that is for every column individually.
•   Then use the results for two dimensional problem.

Comment: just a sideremark: Complexity (e.g. O(n*n)) denotes the **asymptotic** behavior. If you are dealing with very small matrices it may happen, that the brute force solution performs just as well as a more clever approach. Only if you got to high n, the overhead that you have to invest for the more clever approach (including finding a way to do it and implementing it) will pay off.

Comment: I cannot see how you can be more efficient than a single pass method on every elements since you have to compute on each of them. Can you precise your brute force algorithm ?

Comment: My brute force algorithm is O(n^4) for each element I traverse the whole matrix and find nearest non zero element so worst case is O(n^4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need most effective algorithm for such task you can do precondition calculations:

1. Read Matrix ( O(n*n) )
2. Find for each cell nearest left 1 (O(n*n)) store in array A
3. Find for each cell nearest right 1 (O(n*n)) store int array B
4. when you select element(e.g. dist(2,3)) find minimal from A && B arrays (e.g. min(A[2][3], B[2][3]));

So total asymptotic in this case for creating: O(3*N*N), memory: 3*N*N
But for access you will reduce it to O(1)

P.S. resources for initialization can be reduced to O(N) mem: N with combining steps(for example easy combination first and second step), but do it by yourself :)

P.P.S.
Ow I`m a little too harsh and not figured that distance was in euclidian. In this case you can do same as I suggest before. But this asymptotic on initialization will be O(N*N*N), but you can improve it only to O(N*N*log(N)) with graph algrothims like bfs:

1. input matrix
2. create additional array dist and fill it with inf(smth like 1*1000*1000)
3. go through it and find 1
4. start bfs in main directions
5. store in dist array minimal from old value and new calculated (dist[i][j] = min(dist[i][j], calc_dist(i,j, i_1, j_1))

And this algo also can be improved a little bit;

So the main idea of reducing access time for access do precalculation and store them if this possible.

Comment: To avoid having *s interpreted as the start and ends of italics, you can put back-ticks ` around formulas.

Answer (score 0):

First - when comparing distances taken from rect coordiantes, NEVER compare them really, compare their squares instead, counted as dx^2+dy^2. You don't need to waste time on sqrt!

- So, check squares of distances SD from {0,1,2,..., (the farthest
  corner)}. For each one:
- In inner cycle look for all dx>0 & dy>0, such as dx^2+dy^2 = SD.
- In the innermost cycle combine -+ signs for dx, dy.
- Add dx and dy to the source coords.
- Check the result cell for being inside the matrix
- Check the content of the result cell for being 0.

Obviously, the second cycle is the most complex. I would make a help table f(a,b)=a^2+b^2 and look for the SD in it, using that the table is monotonous.

Thus the complexity will be O(n^2) for large distances and the algorithm will be good for nearest distances, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called the Euclidean Distance Transform of the given matrix. There is a paper and an implementation (which computes the Euclidean Distance Transform of images) at http://cs.brown.edu/~pff/dt/. They claim the asymptotic running time of the algorithm is `O(dN)` where `d` is the dimension (`d=2` in your case) and `N` is the number of points (`N = n^2` in your case, where `n` is the size of the matrix).